# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "laso" y "laxo"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, adjetivos

[**Laso**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MxUqyYz) es

> Del lat. *lassus*.
>
> 1. adj. Flojo y macilento.

mientras que [**laxo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N1ka6I5) es

> Del lat. *laxus*.
>
> 1. adj. Flojo, que no tiene la tensión que naturalmente debe tener.

Son dos palabras muy parecidas, tanto en la forma como en el significado. ¿Qué matiz diferencia una de la otra?

Answer (score 4):

"Laxo" suele aplicarse, al menos aquí en España, a directrices, políticas, reglas, personajes de autoridad, etc.

> "La ley prohíbe la descarga ilegal de música, pero es muy **laxa** en su aplicación".

Quiere decir que la ley dice que la descarga ilegal está prohibida pero que la ley no se aplica de forma rígida, queriendo decir que no se castiga o persigue dicho crimen. En ese caso, la ley se está aplicando de forma "floja".

Otro ejemplo:

> "El hotel dice que solo sirve desayuno hasta las 10, pero es muy **laxo** para eso".

En ese caso, el hotel tiene una norma pero no la cumple de forma estricta.

Laso imagino que se aplica más a personas, animales y/o estructuras, pero nunca había visto esa palabra ni la he oído con ese significado, así que al menos en España no es común.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el matiz lo dan las propias definiciones que has puesto: mientras que "laxo" es flojo sin más, **"laso" tiene la connotacion adicional de "macilento"**:

> [**macilento, ta**](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=macilento)
>   Del lat. *macilentus*.
>   1. adj. Flaco y descolorido.

Si consultamos el CORDE para [usos de la palabra en los últimos dos siglos](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=4&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=030717%5C008%5CC000O03072017085722207.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20laso%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20%7BI%7D1800-2017%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&marcas=0), una vez descartados los usos no relacionados con la primera acepción (que son casi todos, la verdad; no es muy usada la acepción que planteas), podemos ver que se utiliza sobre todo en contextos algo negativos, como de enfermedad:

> «*error porfiado, corrupto y laso*»
>   «*Desamayado á un rincón, marchito y laso*»
>   «*Ya se me pone el sol, caduco, laso*»
>   «*Á cuya baja puerta enfermo y laso*»

Etcétera.